# Why does the class attribute disappear from "h1" element rendered by React?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Here is the `render` method of my React.Component:

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {name: "Brian"};
    }

    changeName(name) {
        this.setState({name});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <h1 class="row">hello</h1>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Layout/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And here is the rendered HTML:

```
<div id="app" class="container">
    <h1 data-reactroot="">hello</h1>
</div>
```

I don't understand, why is the `class` attribute of `h1` vanishing?

Comment: In `React` you have to use `className` instead of `class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React elements do not have a `class` property. You have to use `className` property.

The reason for this is provided here, in React's documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Comment: Class is a reserved word in javascript

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `className` instead of `class`

```
<h1 className="row">hello</h1>
```